# How to calculate Gradient of a vectorized equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vectors, matlab, gradient-flows

I am solving a huge optimization problem in `Matlab`. I am now required to obtain gradient of objective function,and nonlinear constraint along their hessien matrix.
As my problem is completely vectorized, I am confused about calculating the gradient of them. Hereby I write a namely vectorized equation that I should take the derivative from. And I want its gradient in Vector form as well (Not 5 different equation regarding to 5x1 dimension of Eq1) 
$P_d=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\x_2 \\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix}$
 `X values are the optimization variables. Note that X3 doesn't participate in the equation at all`
**Some definitions:** 
$P_{dn}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\\mu_o \\x_2\\0 \\x4\end{bmatrix}$, $P_{gn}=\begin{bmatrix}x_2 \\x_1 \\\mu_1 \\x_4\\x1\end{bmatrix}$

Now what is the gradient of this equations:

$Eq1=Sin(P_{dn})+P_{dn}+P_{gn}⊙P_{gn}$ `where ⊙ shows the element-wise multiplication`

Comment: You need to compute the derivatves formally, or numerically (say using finite differences) or directly from the code (such as an number of schemes such as Griewank's). Unless someone is familiar with what you are doing above, it is a lot of work for someone to extract the functional forms from the code above.

Comment: I need analytic (formally)derivative of them. I will write mathematical form of my problem in few minutes. @copper.hat

Comment: Please check if my update is better. @copper.hat

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulty with? It is probably a bit much to expect someone to reverse engineer the above (which looks more like code than a formula) to produce formulae for the gradient/Hessians. You need to isolate what it is that you are having difficulty with rather than just transliterate the code.

Comment: I edited my question again  and added a math formulation and removed my earlier equation. I think this is more clear for mathmatitions and this will help me to solve my original problem. @copper.hat

Comment: From what I can tell, you have a map $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^5$, so the derivative (not gradient) will also be a map  $\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^5$. It is not particularly hard to compute the elements directly as $[DF(x)]_{ij} = {\partial F_i(x) \over \partial x_j}$, where $F$ is your Eqn1 above.

Comment: why not gradient? I think I need to supply the gradient of Eq1 to matlab `fmincon` solver. I guess it will be a matrix of [5x4].  @copper.hat

Comment: Well, a gradient has a specific meaning for a functional in an inner product space, but that is just nomenclature. You can compute the derivative directly, for example ${\partial \text{Eq1}_1(x) \over \partial x_1} = \cos x_1 + 1$.